# How to control the Bit Rate (mbps) of a Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: linux, networking

I have two "Raspberry Pi 3 B+" boards which are required to be connected. One Raspberry Pi is configured as Access Point (AP) and the other one is just a Client. When both are connected, I write the command "iwconfig" on the Client side which shows the specifications of the network with which the Client is connected to(AP). In the specs i see "Bit Rate = 72.2 mbps" which varies after sometimes. Sometimes it shows 65 mbps sometimes 48 mbps and then again 72.2 mbps. How can i make this Bit Rate constant? I have tried changing the modes of AP from its hostapd.conf file. I have tried

(1)

```
hw_mode=g
```

(2)

```
hw_mode=b
```

(3)

```
 hw_mode=g
 ieee80211n=1
 wmm_enabled=1
```

But nothing has changed, the Client is still showing Bit Rate = 72.2 mbps which varies after sometimes.How can i make this Bit Rate constant? 
Please help me in this regards. I will be very thankful.

Comment: The Bit Rate that a wireless connection obtains depends on many factors.  [This web page](https://hpbn.co/introduction-to-wireless-networks/) has a wealth of information on this subject.  It would be helpful if you could post all of the data output by the `iwconfig` command each time you run it.  From that we might see that you have a lower signal strength when you see a lower bit rate.  Or possibly higher noise.

Answer (score 2):

This is not Raspberry Pi specific, so I don't understand why this question was migrated.

**All** WLAN hardware will negotiate the optimal bitrate between an AP and a client based on signal strength, error rate and other factors.

While you can configure the *possible* bit rates to some degree, there's no way to keep it "constant", and keeping it "constant" won't improve your reception - if you artificially push the bit rate too high, the error rate will also increase, so the actual throughput will be *lower*.

So: hands off, the manufacturers of WLAN devices spend time optimizing this feedback loop; there's no reason to mess with it.

**Edit**

To configure the *possible* bit rates for the AP, edit the `hostapd.conf` file. From the file supplied as example in the `hostapd` documentation:

```
# Rate configuration
# Default is to enable all rates supported by the hardware. This configuration
# item allows this list be filtered so that only the listed rates will be left
# in the list. If the list is empty, all rates are used. This list can have
# entries that are not in the list of rates the hardware supports (such entries
# are ignored). The entries in this list are in 100 kbps, i.e., 11 Mbps = 110.
# If this item is present, at least one rate have to be matching with the rates
# hardware supports.
# default: use the most common supported rate setting for the selected
# hw_mode (i.e., this line can be removed from configuration file in most
# cases)
#supported_rates=10 20 55 110 60 90 120 180 240 360 480 540
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. By making the Bit Rate constant means to make it limited to some extent for example, i want to limit the Bit Rate to 11 mbps maximum or to 54 mbps maximum. Can i do it? Just don't want to have the Bit Rate too high.